# checking if an ODBC DSN exists?

Tags: c#, odbc, dsn

I've been using the registry to check if a given DSN exists using the code:

```
private const string ODBC_INI_REG_PATH = "SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\";
public static bool DSNExists(string dsnName)
{
    var sourcesKey = Registry
        .LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(ODBC_INI_REG_PATH + "ODBC Data Sources");
    if (sourcesKey == null) 
        throw new Exception("ODBC Registry key for sources does not exist");
    string[] blah = sourcesKey.GetValueNames();
    Console.WriteLine("length: " + blah.Length); //prints: 0
    return sourcesKey.GetValue(dsnName) != null;
}
```

There is definitely not 0 DSNs and the DSN I am passing in as a parameter does actually exist yet it is returning false. I can't figure out why?

Comment: Try running [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) whilst you're doing this to see exactly where it's looking in the registry.

Comment: Maybe you are looking at the wrong registry? The 32-bit vs 64 bit registry thing was driving me nuts with getting my system DSN's right. I think "Registry.LocalMachine" goes by if you are compiling as x86 vs x64.

Comment: @Mike This could be possible I was getting some 32bit and 64bit mismatches before. I have a 64bit windows 7 machine how do I access the 64bit registry?

Comment: *I think* if you are compiling as x64, it will go to the 64 bit registry automatically, if you are trying to get to a 32 bit DSN (which is what I do since my DSN's are for Office 2007 on 64 bit Windows 7), you would use SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\... If you are compiling x86, getting to 64 bit registry requires PInvoke, If you are compiling "as Any" I do not remember what happens but I saw a chart somewhere once.

Comment: I am using DSNs for Access 2007 so I assume then these are 32-bit DSNs? I have a 64 bit machine. which registry and which should I be compiling as?

Comment: Compile as either Any or x64, use the Wow6432Node subkey.

Answer (score 6):

I was looking how to do this in PowerShell, and while not strictly an answer to this question, since it did come up in my searches I figure I can leave a note here:

```
if ( (Get-OdbcDsn -Name $DSN -CimSession $OnHost -ErrorAction Ignore) -ne $null)
{
    # Code here runs if the DSN exists.
}
```

Additional parameters can be added to check specific platform.

Comment: I'm not a PowerShell guy, but I believe this is what's currently required. Note `ErrorAction` so it doesn't vomit to the console, and `ne`, not `neq`:

`if ( (Get-OdbcDsn -Name $DSN -CimSession $OnHost -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -ne $null)`

Comment: Thanks @nullPainter, not sure where `neq` came from. I fixed it. It seems I have `Ignore` for error action in my production script, which also avoids putting the error in `$Error`. And btw, if anyone wonders, as I did, this does (thankfully) NOT suppress errors from "CimSession" such as wrong hostname or host not responding. You still get those errors, so you can avoid wrongfully picking either option if the answer could not be determined.

Answer (score 3):

First you have to wonder if the machine where the program is being run is x86 or x64:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Determines if the current application is 32 or 64-bit.
    /// se retorno == 32 = x86 else x64
    /// </summary>
    public int Bits()
    {
        return IntPtr.Size * 8;
    }
```

After that, set the registry path. The role that made for my application I used the variable is64 as int. If the variable is assigned the value 32 the system is x86, x64 is otherwise

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Construtor da classe
    /// a variavel is64 vai receber um numero inteiro (32 ou 64) representando a arquitetura da maquina
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="is64"></param>
    public Odbc(int is64)
    {
        if (is64 == 32)
        {
            this.ODBC_INI_REG_PATH = "Software\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\";
            this.ODBCINST_INI_REG_PATH = "Software\\ODBC\\ODBCINST.INI\\";
        }
        else
        {
            this.ODBC_INI_REG_PATH = "Software\\Wow6432Node\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\";
            this.ODBCINST_INI_REG_PATH = "Software\\Wow6432Node\\ODBC\\ODBCINST.INI\\";
        }
    }
```

Finally I modified the function you put on topic. The modification was:

Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey => Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey

```
public bool DSNExists(string dsnName)
    {
        try
        {
            var sourcesKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(this.ODBC_INI_REG_PATH + "ODBC Data Sources");

            if (sourcesKey == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("ODBC Registry key for sources does not exist");
            }

            string[] blah = sourcesKey.GetValueNames();

            Console.WriteLine("length: " + blah.Length); //prints: 0

            return sourcesKey.GetValue(dsnName) != null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

DSNs aren't values of that path, they're sub keys. You probably want something like:

```
private const string ODBC_INI_REG_PATH = "SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\";
public static bool DSNExists(string dsnName)
{
    var sourcesKey = Registry
        .LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(ODBC_INI_REG_PATH + "ODBC Data Sources");
    if (sourcesKey == null) 
        throw new Exception("ODBC Registry key for sources does not exist");
    string[] blah = sourcesKey.GetSubKeyNames();
    Console.WriteLine("length: " + blah.Length);
    var dsnKey = sourcesKey.OpenSubKey(dsnName);
    bool exists = (dsnKey != null);
    if (exists) dsnKey.Close();
    sourcesKey.Close();
    return exists;
}
```

Note that

1. I've switched GetValueNames() for GetSubKeyNames()
2. I'm opening the sub key to check for existence: I'm not sure if there's a better way, or if that's better than doing a Contains on the GetSubKeyNames result.
3. I think you should really Close keys after you've opened them to release the handle.

Comment: I'm still getting 0 and the dsn I know exists that im passing in as a parameter is still returning false. Perhaps there is some relevance to Mike's comment about a 32-bit registry and 64-bit?

Comment: Oh, I don't know then sorry - that code works for me. The 32/64 thing is that rather than SOFTWARE\ODBC you'd look under SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC, or perhaps your code is automatically translating your request to insert the Wow6432Node for you: I can't remember the rules.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to know how to check with PowerShell whether a DSN exists, because I wanted to avoid the error message that occurs if I try to use Remove-OdbcDsn when the DSN does not exist. Now, instead of trying to check whether it exists, I just run Remove-OdbcDsn with "-ErrorAction Ignore". If the DSN exists, it is removed; if not, the script silently moves on. Perfect!
Thx @ Oskar Berggren.